# Opção ao Hyper-v Manager para Windows 10 Home

Tags: hyper-v

Sempre que precisei acessar máquinas virtuais no servidor do hyper-v utilizei o hyper-v manager. Porém, o hyper-v manager não é disponibilizado para versões home do Windows.

Existe alguma alternativa, sem utilizar o hyper-v manager, para acessar o servidor de virtualização com Hyper-v?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de conversa com amigos que acessam máquinas virtuais em servidor Hyper-v a partir de distribuições Linux, e alguma pesquisa, fui apresentado ao [Hypy](https://github.com/avanzzzi/hypy). Uma aplicação feita em Python, que funciona perfeitamente para acessar máquinas virtuais em servidor Hyper-v sem a necessidade de utilizar o Hyper-v manager.